# Dask in-place replacement of pandas?

Tags: dask

I will like to know if I can use dask instead of pandas. What are the issues I may face?

1) I guess dask will be slower than pandas for smaller datasets. I am OK with that because there are times when I do not know the size of the data nor do I know server configuration.

2) I will have to learn a slightly different syntax (for e.g. compute)

Will I face a situation where dask dataframe can not do something that pandas dataframe can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very broad question.  In general I recommend referring to the [dask.dataframe documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).

Dask.dataframe does not implement all pandas.  This includes the following sorts of operations:

1. Mutating operations
2. Operations that are hard to do exactly in parallel, like median, (though approximate solutions often exist, like approximate quantiles)
3. Iterating over rows of a dataframe
4. Small corners of the API that no one has bothered to copy over.

However, because a dask dataframe is just a collection of many small dataframes, you can often get around some of these limitations in simple cases.